# How to : ListView animation ( add/remove item )

Tags: android, sql, listview

I have : ListView which gets SimpleCursorAdapter from SQLDatabase.
I need : animation (item slowly appears or disappears) when some data was added to or removed from database.

P.S.
I need example using ONLY  LayoutAnimationController

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please, see: http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=343

Documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#attr_android%3alayoutAnimation

Comment: LayoutAnimation does not apply to Adapter based ViewGroups. See this tutorial instead: http://graphics-geek.blogspot.com/2013/06/devbytes-animating-listview-deletion.html